# How to enqueue more than one build of the same configuration?

Tags: teamcity

We are using two teamcity servers (one for builds and one for GUI tests). The gui tests are triggered from http GET in the last step of the build. (as in http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP)
The problem is, that there is only one configuration of the same kind in the queue at the same time. Is there a way to enable multiple starts of the same configuration? Can I use some workaround like sending a dummy id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom the section "Triggering a Custom Build" here: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP, you can find information about passing custom parameters to the build.

Just define some unused configuration parameter, like "BuildId", and pass, for example, current date (guid will work as well) to it

```
...&buildId=12/12/23 12:12:12
```

Comment: I completely missed that part :)